# Veracrypt - When using Full OS encryption, isn't it easier to decrypt using the OS file placement?

Tags: encryption, operating-systems, forensics, cryptanalysis, veracrypt

Let say you encrypt A.jpg and B.jpg , B is just after A in the hard drive.

let say A = 0101 B = 1001

on unencrypted HDD : AB = 01011001

once encrypted : AB = 11111011

if someone know A is the first bits and know A = 0101

would it be easier for an attacker to know the password by comparing the data of both encrypted and unencrypted data ?

so in that case, in a fresh install of Windows 7, if I encrypt it,

wouldn't an attacker compare ***his*** windows 7's first bits to find a correlation between ***my*** windows 7's first bits and find my password ?

(sorry for my English...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a properly implemented encryption scheme, comparing the encrypted and unencrypted data **does not provide any clues** about the password used to encrypt, as you seem to think.

Any high quality Symmetric Encryption algorithm will include an **Avalanche Effect** so that if even a single bit of the key is wrong, then the entire result will appear random, and therefore not provide any clues. The attacker does not know whether a guessed key is slightly wrong, or completely wrong.

Also note that the Encryption/Decryption **Key** is actually **Derived** from the user's **Password** using a Key Derivation function. The purpose of using a Key Derivation function is to create a **fixed-length key** (i.e. 128 bit key for an AES-128 encryption) based on a **variable length password** (i.e. most passwords are less than 128 bits), including its own avalanche effect. Also the Key Derivation function is usually somewhat processor intensive to reduce the amount of **Entropy** required for a password to be safe from brute force.

(In your example, it seems you have a XOR cipher, which does not include an avalanche effect.)